# How to fix the killed/rollback state issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, kill, xp-cmdshell

When I was running some cmd through xp_cmdshell in sql server it tooks long time to execute.So I have killed the session.But it stucks in KILLED/ROLLBACK state for long time.Its a standalone production server.I cant restart this server.Is this a performance issue? Is there any way to clear that session?

Comment: how much it took time ? how much record we are talking ? are there indexex ? as far as i know you have to wait to rollback unless you migh loose data

Comment: what sort of script were you running?

Comment: exec xp_cmdshell 'typeperf "\LogicalDisk(*)\Avg. Disk sec/Read"' @maSTAShuFu

Comment: Actually which was cmdshell command and did not return any output @Moudiz

Comment: try KILL spid WITH STATUSONLY; to get a progress report and an estimated time to rollback

Comment: progress 0% @SteveFord

Comment: @SujithTee I think that xp_cmdshell spawns a windows process to run. You need to find this windows process and kill it. Take a look at this link https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1733632-391-1.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kill the windows process linked to `xp_cmdshell` and if it does not rollback I guess the only solution will be to restart the instance.

Comment: Any way to do this programatically within SQL? IE have an agent job that automatically kills a windows process if its been stuck in that state for more than x minutes?

Comment: There may be, but actually asking your system administrator would be the best bet

Comment: How to protect against a process run from xp_cmdshell remaining in KILLED/ROLLBACK state forever? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59838503/how-to-protect-against-a-process-run-from-xp-cmdshell-remaining-in-killed-rollba